# how to get all the text in the TD from a table in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I would like to get all the text inside td tag, I have tried to do following,

```
<table id="tab1">
<tr>
  <td>a</td>
  <td>b</td>
  <td>c</td>
  <td>d</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: "I have tried to do following" ... then just an HTML table. Did you forget to include something in your post?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should give a class for your td cells.

I defined a class "text-cell" for each td in table.

```
$("#tab1 td.text-cell").each(function () {
    var txt = $(this).html();
});
```